# Comment dire « stepmother-in-law » en français?

Tags: choix-de-mot, société

Le terme « marâtre » n'est plus utilisé aujourd'hui pour désigner la *stepmother* contemporaine. « Belle-mère » a pris le dessus et désigne maintenant cette personne, de même que la mère de son conjoint ou sa conjointe. Or, qu'advient-il de la nouvelle conjointe du père de notre partenaire? L'addition usuelle du qualificatif « belle » au lien de parenté nous donne « belle-belle-mère », ce que je trouve très gênant. Existe-t-il une alternative?

Cette question se pose évidemment également pour l'équivalent masculin.

Comment: Belle-marâtre ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

En tant que Française, je n'aurais pas compris une expression du type "belle-mère par alliance". Je pense que quelque chose comme la "femme du père de mon conjoint" est bien plus naturel. Cette expression sous-entend que la femme en question n'est pas la mère du conjoint.

Answer (score 6):

J'utiliserais soit le terme *belle-mère* directement, soit *belle-mère par alliance* s'il y a la nécessité de lever l'ambigüité, par exemple si on veut marquer la différence d'avec la mère biologique du partenaire.

Le terme *par alliance* n'est cependant habituellement utilisé que pour décrire l'alliance avec le partenaire, et non une alliance d'un membre de sa famille.

Une autre possibilité serait simplement *la femme de mon beau-père*, si le contexte implique que *beau-père* fait référence au père de notre partenaire, et non au nouveau conjoint de notre mère.

Comment: Je ferai de même. « Belle-mère », « beau-père » sous-entend à un niveau une alliance et un absence de lien de « sang » (en excluant les adoptions pour simplifier). On se retrouve avec un terme plus simple, plus passe-partout, et où le contexte fera le reste.